# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\\xa0' in position 59, python 3.8

Tags: python

I try to upload a file but have some issue, help

```
                file_data = request.FILES.get(local_file_name)  # read file

                # with default_storage.open(upload_file_path, 'wb') as new_file:  # write down
                with default_storage.open(upload_file_path, mode="wb") as new_file:  
                    for chunk in file_data.chunks(): 
                        new_file.write(chunk)
                    new_file.close()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/www/warehouse/isoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner 

 response = get_response(request)

  File "/var/www/warehouse/isoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response 
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/var/www/warehouse/isoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view 
  return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/warehouse/isoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view 
  return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/warehouse/slot/views.py", line 746, in uploads, 
  with default_storage.open(upload_file_path, 'wb') as new_file: \xe5\x86\x99\xe5\x85\xa5\xe7\xa9\xba\xe6\x96\x87\xe4\xbb\xb6\xe5\x88\xb0\xe6\x9c\x8d\xe5\x8a\xa1\xe5\x99\xa8

 File "/var/www/warehouse/isoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 36, in open 
  return self._open(name, mode)

 File "/var/www/warehouse/isoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py"
   return File(open(self.path(name), mode))

 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\\xa0' in position 59: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: That isn't the full traceback, and without the full traceback, it's entirely unclear what the code you posted has to do with the error. We need a [MCVE] to have a chance of helping you.

Comment: `ascii` isn't Unicode, it's the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage. Which btw is identical to the first 127 characters of UTF8. Did you try to open a UTF8 file by specifying `ascii`? This will fail with *all* non-English text, and even with may English words that contain diacritics. Try loading the text without specifying any encoding, or specifying `utf-8`

Comment: then how can I do ?

Comment: with this amount of provided information, I can only think that the problem lies in the `open` part of your code, try to include encoding too. see what happens. trythis code `with default_storage.open(upload_file_path, mode="wb", encoding='utf-8') as new_file:`

Comment: with default_storage.open(upload_file_path, mode="wb", encoding='utf-8') as new_file:
TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'